# PHP - radio button without submit button

Tags: php, html

test.php

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
Q1: <br />
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="true" />T<br />(Correct Answer)
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="false" />F<br />

Q2: <br />
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="true" />T<br />
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="false" />F<br />(Correct Answer)

<input type="submit" value="Score" />
</form>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
     //process code from test.php
?>
```

I want to get the value of the radio buttons from each question and check whether is true or false. I try this in test2.php:
(1) `if($_POST['name'])` -> get error (undefined index: name)
(2) `if($_POST['submit'])` -> get error(undefined index: submit)
(3) `if(isset($_POST['name'])`-> no error, but nothing happened

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have named the radio button as `q1` and `q2` but trying to access it with a name `name`. Instead of `if($_POST['name'])` you have to do like

```
if($_POST['q1'])
```

and

```
if($_POST['q2'])
```

Also for checking whether the form is submitted or not, you can try this code.

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

In case if you are using `if($_POST['submit'])` for checking whether the form is submitted or not, `submit` will be the name of the submit button. So you have to set `name` property to submit button.

```
<input name="submit"  type="submit" value="Score" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jenz. I finally understand it. Use the value of the radio button, not the name of the radio button.

Comment: not value. Use the name of input elements while you are submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$_POST['q1'];
$_POST['q2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **name**:

```
<input name="submit"  type="submit" value="Score" />
```

and to get the value like this:

```
$_POST['q1'];
$_POST['q2'];
```

the **name** attribute is what you send in `POST/GET` to the php script.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//don't forget to check using isset()
   {
    /*other variables*/
    $radio_value1 = $_POST['q1'];
    $radio_value2 = $_POST['q2'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if($_POST['name'])

to

```
if($_POST['q1']) {

}

if($_POST['q2']) {

}
```

if(isset($_POST['name'])

to

```
if(isset($_POST['q1']) 
if(isset($_POST['q2'])
```

And,

```
<input type="submit" value="Score" /> to <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score" />
```